# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve UDF(df["columnName"])

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a requirement of generating the Select expression (with coalesce fucntion and UDF-checkNullUdf) dynamically based on few conditions. for which  I have written the code as below:

```
column_expr=''
for row in PRIORITIZATION.rdd.collect():
    x=row.__fields__
    colName=row.Element
    i=0
    lst=['']
    for col in row:
        if (col is not None and i != 0 and i != 1) :
            dfColName="checkNullUdf("+x[i]+"[\""+colName+"\"])"
            lst.insert(int(col)-1,dfColName)
        i+=1
    lst.remove('')
    print(lst)
    lst=",".join(lst)
    column_expr=column_expr+"coalesce("+lst+"),"
column_expr=column_expr[:-1]
print("Final String is: " +column_expr)
```

which gives the below output as expected

```
Final String is: coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Well_Name"]),checkNullUdf(SAP["Well_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Country"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["City"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["State"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Spud_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Plug_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(WEBBIT["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Water_Depth"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["County"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Operator"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Field_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Long"]))
```

But while passing this string to the select expression as below I am getting an error:

```
RESULT_REC = GOLDEN_RECORD.join(BITPULSE, GOLDEN_RECORD.BitPulse_rec_Id==BITPULSE.UUID, "left_outer").join(SAP, GOLDEN_RECORD.SAP_rec_Id==SAP.UUID, "left_outer").join(WEBBIT, GOLDEN_RECORD.MDM_Well_Id==WEBBIT.UUID, "left_outer").join(WELLDB, GOLDEN_RECORD.WellDB_rec_Id==WELLDB.UUID, "left_outer").select(column_expr)
```

The error is as below:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Well_Name"]),checkNullUdf(SAP["Well_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Country"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["City"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["State"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Spud_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Plug_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(WEBBIT["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Water_Depth"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["County"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Operator"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Field_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Long"]))`' given input columns: [State, Country, UUID, County, City, WellDB_rec_Id, Spud_Date, UUID, Well_Name, Water_Depth, State, Spud_Date, UUID, SAP_rec_Id, Country, Plug_Date, County, State, UUID, Spud_Date, Field_Name, BitPulse_rec_Id, Operator, Well_Name, Water_Depth, Country, MDM_Well_Id, UUID, Water_Depth, Field_Name, Well_Name, Long];;
'Project ['coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Well_Name"]),checkNullUdf(SAP["Well_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Country"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["City"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["State"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Spud_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Plug_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(WEBBIT["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Water_Depth"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["County"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Operator"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Field_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Long"]))]
+- Join LeftOuter, (WellDB_rec_Id#14 = UUID#124)
   :- Join LeftOuter, (MDM_Well_Id#11 = UUID#108)
   :  :- Join LeftOuter, (SAP_rec_Id#12 = UUID#88)
   :  :  :- Join LeftOuter, (BitPulse_rec_Id#13 = UUID#40)
   :  :  :  :- Relation[UUID#10,MDM_Well_Id#11,SAP_rec_Id#12,BitPulse_rec_Id#13,WellDB_rec_Id#14,Well_Name#15,Country#16,Operator#17,Field_Name#18,Long#19] csv
   :  :  :  +- Relation[UUID#40,Spud_Date#41,Plug_Date#42,Water_Depth#43,Field_Name#44,State#45,County#46] csv
   :  :  +- Relation[UUID#88,Well_Name#89,Country#90,City#91,State#92] csv
   :  +- Relation[UUID#108,Spud_Date#109,Water_Depth#110] csv
   +- Relation[UUID#124,Well_Name#125,State#126,County#127,Country#128,Spud_Date#129,Water_Depth#130] csv
--------------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException: 'cannot resolve \'`coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Well_Name"]),checkNullUdf(SAP["Well_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Country"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["City"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["State"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Spud_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Plug_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(WEBBIT["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Water_Depth"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["County"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Operator"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Field_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Long"]))`\' given input columns: [State, Country, UUID, County, City, WellDB_rec_Id, Spud_Date, UUID, Well_Name, Water_Depth, State, Spud_Date, UUID, SAP_rec_Id, Country, Plug_Date, County, State, UUID, Spud_Date, Field_Name, BitPulse_rec_Id, Operator, Well_Name, Water_Depth, Country, MDM_Well_Id, UUID, Water_Depth, Field_Name, Well_Name, Long];;\n\'Project [\'coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Well_Name"]),checkNullUdf(SAP["Well_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Country"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["City"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(SAP["State"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Spud_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Plug_Date"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(WEBBIT["Water_Depth"]),checkNullUdf(BITPULSE["Water_Depth"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(WELLDB["County"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Operator"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Field_Name"])),coalesce(checkNullUdf(GOLDEN_RECORD["Long"]))]\n+- Join LeftOuter, (WellDB_rec_Id#14 = UUID#124)\n   :- Join LeftOuter, (MDM_Well_Id#11 = UUID#108)\n   :  :- Join LeftOuter, (SAP_rec_Id#12 = UUID#88)\n   :  :  :- Join LeftOuter, (BitPulse_rec_Id#13 = UUID#40)\n   :  :  :  :- Relation[UUID#10,MDM_Well_Id#11,SAP_rec_Id#12,BitPulse_rec_Id#13,WellDB_rec_Id#14,Well_Name#15,Country#16,Operator#17,Field_Name#18,Long#19] csv\n   :  :  :  +- Relation[UUID#40,Spud_Date#41,Plug_Date#42,Water_Depth#43,Field_Name#44,State#45,County#46] csv\n   :  :  +- Relation[UUID#88,Well_Name#89,Country#90,City#91,State#92] csv\n   :  +- Relation[UUID#108,Spud_Date#109,Water_Depth#110] csv\n   +- Relation[UUID#124,Well_Name#125,State#126,County#127,Country#128,Spud_Date#129,Water_Depth#130] csv\n'
20/04/07 00:53:33 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

but if I copy paste the Final String output in select expression, It is working Fine and I am getting expected output.

Not Sure why I am getting the error while passing column_expr

Answer (score 1):

Use `selectExpr` instead of `select`.  If you look at the error you can see back ticks around the whole expression which means Spark is trying to find a column whose name matches that WHOLE string.  `selectExpr` will evaluate each parameter you pass in as a SQL expression resulting in one column, whereas `select` expects each parameter to be a named column.

**Also noteworthy:**

It's hard to track through your intent with the code posted, but there are some suspect things here.  The biggest one that jumps out at me is `checkNullUdf`. 
 UDFs will have significantly worse performance than using built in functions.  You also appear to be doing a `collect` to get column names, which unless there is something special about their values is unnecessary because you can just use `DataFrame.columns`.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Wildmaier!! selectExpr helped to an extend but I got final success with eval() function. For UDF, we have a special requirement of handling the files from different sources where a Null values can be None/none/<empty string>/spaces/Nul/null. to handle all type of nulls UDF is written. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You could still do that w/o a UDF.  define a function that returns a column and checks for all those.  for example: `def is_null(c): return c.isNull() | (c.isin("", "none", "null"))`

Comment: Windmaier !!! I was unaware of the same in python/pyspark. Thanks for the information. It works great !!!

Comment: @Ankit If you find this answer helpful, you should mark it as such with the up arrow to the left. If the answer completely solves your problem, please mark it as the correct answer. It helps the community find the answers they are looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run a String SQL expression by using `spar.sql(" SQL expression as a String ")`

```
val employees = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("E1",100.0,"a,b"), ("E2",200.0,"e,f"),(null,300.0,"c,d"))).toDF("employee","salary","clubs")

employees.createTempView("employees")
spark.sql("select coalesce(employee,salary) as emp_or_sal from employees").show()
```

Result -

```
+----------+
|emp_or_sal|
+----------+
|        E1|
|        E2|
|     300.0|
+----------+
```